# jQUery UI draggable - read when an item is over particular element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am trying to add a border when the draggable item is over particular element. What should I use to read the event?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Post the code you've tried in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after several hours, I found that the event can be read by adding `over` on the `droppable`element.

example:

```
$(".dragable").draggable();
$(".dropable").droppable({
    over :function() {
       alert($(this).atrr("id"));
    }
});
```